Can't record a video from a Window of size 886x1920px
I have an application with a window of size 886x1920px and can't record a video from that window of exactly the same size.
If I try to record with Win + Alt + R I get the video of size 672×1440px.
If I try OBS with the following settings:


I get the video of size 884x1920px but not 886x1920px:

Is it an OBS bug?
How to record exactly 886x1920px?
For example, I can easily record 1200x1060px or 1080x1920px with OBS.
VLC media player displays the following media information:

as you can see, the buffer dimension differs from video resolution, for example.
My screen resolution (with Nvidia DSR):

EDIT1:
At least I found out how to resize the video on Ubuntu WSL:
ffmpeg -i iphone884.mp4 -vf scale=886:1920,setsar=1 -c:a copy iphone886.mp4


Did you try a different encoder or format?

@Destroy666 Tried QuickTime, MPEG-TS formats and Hardware/Software encoders with the same result.

Probably a related question about different resolutions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573468/using-ffmpeg-to-scale-app-preview-videos-for-the-appstore
